# Splice Inside Panel - Splice Neutral Or Attach To Bus?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, splices

When creating a splice inside a breaker panel cabinet, I know that you typically use a splice and pigtail to connect multiple hot wires to a single breaker.

I have a circuit with a single device (switched ceiling light) on the breaker. I’m adding a receptacle in the same room and don’t (didn’t) want to waste another breaker for another single device. A junction box outside the panel cabinet is a perfectly acceptable solution and actually what I did today. I am merely curious about the best practice with regards to the neutral and ground when using the cabinet as a junction box.

As far as the neutral(s) and ground(s), what’s the best practice?

Splice multiple wires and pigtail to the respective bus or use a direct connection of each wire to the respective bus - assuming there is room on the bus bar, of course.

[image: panel]

Answer (score 4):

Best practice is that every neutral and ground should go directly to a bus bar, even if spliced. A splice is OK if you need extra length, but *not* to combine wires.

Why, you ask, is a multiple splice a problem for neutral and ground but not for hot? Because of *changes*. Simple example:

- New circuit added for lighting only, so low usage. Spliced hot together with an existing circuit.
- Neutral installed at the same time is spliced as well, since that makes sense.
- Future upgrade using the "lighting only" circuit for receptacles, including high power ones such as space heaters, results in nuisance trips.
- Diagnosis determines the problem. Install a new breaker and unsplice the hot so that you now have two separate circuits. But neutral is ignored, because it isn't an obvious problem.
- **30A long term usage on the neutral (12 AWG, 20A rating) pigtail causes a fire.**

Now that is a big combination of problems. The reality is that it will probably never become that big a problem, just as many messed-up MWBCs (my electrician and I discovered one in an old panel during my heavy-up) will never cause a problem. But the concern is definitely there.

The good news: There are *usually* more than enough neutral and ground bar positions available. In the case of ground bars, 2 or even 3 wires per terminal are usually permitted, but it does vary by panel. Adding ground bars is usually easy to do as well. In the case of neutral bars, it can get a bit messy, particularly if there are a lot of tandem/half-size breakers (2 neutrals for 1 breaker space) and very few double-breakers (240V, 0 or 1 neutral for 2 breaker spaces).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation/reasoning. In this case, I’m not sure there are any open neutral spots on the bar and I’m pretty sure multiple grounds aren’t permissible. I’ll get the model and check. It’ll probably be easier to just add a junction box for the new run outside the cabinet. Thanks again.

Comment: A picture of the panel (with the front cover off so we can see the wires, ground and neutral bars, etc.) and the panel label would help

Comment: Then do an accessory ground bar @derbydad.  Grounds are allowed as guests on the neutral bar in the main panel, but they can be evicted to an accessory ground bar.  Typically under $8, and compatible models of ground bar should be listed on the panel labeling.  There is typically more than one location designed for them, so feel free to populate more than one if it'll help with reach.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact As it turns out I have 2 empty lugs for neutrals and more than enough open spots for a ground. In any case, I went with an external junction box instead of an internal splice. Since you asked, here's a pic of the panel. All of the Wago splices are merely extensions, not the type of splices we've been discussing in this thread. https://i.imgur.com/w6mlKf7.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a reason anyone would splice ground wires together if they were long enough and a place for them to land existed. Splicing grounds is not a problem; in fact, all the equipment ground wires in a box, be they from however many distinct circuits, are required by electrical code to be spliced together. It's quite different with the neutral wires, as different circuits cannot be combined that way. The virtues of simplicity and flexibility would best be served by landing each incoming neutral conductor separately on the neutral bar, even if a splice would be allowable. No one wants to deal with a wire nut buried behind 27 other conductors in the load center.

Comment: No argument. My panel was full of buried wire nuts which not only made it a PITA to work in, but it looked like crap. They were the result of a new panel install (not done by me) which required at least half of the circuits to be extended. I recently replaced all of the wire nuts with Wago connectors. It went from this (both sides) https://i.imgur.com/E4By8ib.jpg and this https://i.imgur.com/MYY5hsh.jpg to this https://i.imgur.com/w6mlKf7.jpg